# Converting chrome extension written in php to IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, ieaddon

There is a PHP web-app for which we have developed a chrome extension for easy accessing some of apps functionality without really switching to actual app.

Now I want to do the same for IE. The minimum IE version can be 8. I goggled the web for the guides and techniques for creating an IE toolbar extension, but all I got is to create an extension using Visual Studio in C#,VB.NET and C++. So this means, I need to code my application from scratch in one of the supported languages.

So is there any way by which I either I can convert my chrome extension to IE or can use PHP for developing IE(if coding from scratch is the only solution)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way by which I either I can convert my chrome extension to IE

No. Internet Explorer <del>/ Edge</del> browsers do not have the same JavaScript-based extension architecture. Add-ons for IE are like modules of the program itself, and built using those native languages.

Please note: Internet Explorer is on its way out, <del>and Edge currently does not support *any* kind of add-ons</del>.

**Update:** Edge now [supports extension development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/) using a Chrome-like model. That means JavaScript as the language. It's in its early days as of Sep 2016, see [the roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/extension-API-roadmap/).

> Can use PHP for developing IE(if coding from scratch is the only solution)

..no.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Edge now supports extension development in the same vein as Firefox's WebExtensions: a partial (and growing) reimplementation of the Chrome extension model.